# Python Replace string if outside double quotes else ignore

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a `JSON` with the following data:

```
{"name":"John", "isAdult":True, "Address":"42 True Street SomeLand"}
```

I only want to replace `True` with `"True"` using Python `re` module if it is outside double quotes if within double quotes then I want to ignore it.

Sample output:

```
{"name":"John", "isAdult":"True", "Address":"42 True Street SomeLand"}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the reason I want to replace it because json.loads (as I am getting string) fails.

Comment: But where does this come from? It sounds like you are trying to fix a problem in the wrong place. You should fix it at the source where the data is serialized to JSON rather than after the fact.

Comment: Is this really a string? Or is it a dictionary? Please show a complete example where this is used.

Comment: I don't have control over the source hence need to handle this at the client side.

Comment: that's not a JSON file. in JSON files, `True` is spelled `true`. Try parsing it with `ast.literal_eval` instead; it could be a Python dictionary literal.

Comment: @JavaMan I would report a bug to the source because they are not sending you valid JSON.

Comment: If the data is following your sample, why not just replace `:True,` to `:"true",` (or to upper... whatever).

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice - agreed regarding your bug comment and will take this up. However, if we just treat True as a string and look at a generic problem to only replace if found outside double quote then do you think we can code this using Python re?

Comment: @JavaMan This is a larger problem than you can solve with regular expressions, at least if you want it to be robust. A first pass might be to replace `:True` with `:true`. However, that still encounters the same problem if `:True` appears inside any quotes. You might be able to get around this if you know this combination of characters won't appear anywhere else.

Comment: Another solution is as @kindal suggested: use `ast.literal_eval` since this string is a valid dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you mean this is a string:

```
'{"name":"John", "isAdult":True, "Address":"42 True Street SomeLand"}'
```

This is not valid JSON. For boolean values, JSON requires `true` and `false` to be all lower case.

The ideal solution here is to fix this at the source so that it is correct JSON. If you don't have control over that, then the simplest approach is to replace `:True` with `:true`. You can similarly do this for `:False` if needed. You may also need to allow for arbitrary whitespace after the `:`. Note that this solution is more general and avoids the need to worry about quotes.

Comment: And now that I think about it further...you still have the same problem. What if `:True` appears somewhere else, say inside a quoted string. I think the most robust solution would be to build a parser, which isn't trivial and requires more than just a regular expression.

Comment: To be honest, I have deployed a tactical solution to replace True with "true" before I pass the data to json.loads however, I am worried what if in case I receive True within double quotes as there I won't like to touch it.

Comment: You can try replacing `":True`, this is incrementally less likely to appear in quoted strings than `:True`

Comment: or maybe `(?!^\\)":True` since most of the time, a quote inside quotes would need to be escaped

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use negative lookbehind: `(?<!\\)":True`

Comment: Thanks @Kindall, don't think you need to apologise for anything. Massive thanks once again for responding to my question. Cheers mate !!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot @Code-Apprentice and @kindall for your valuable inputs, please find below the code that works:

```
import re

pattern = r'(?!^\\)":True'
text='{"name":"John", "isAdult":True, "Address":"42 True Street SomeLand"}'
x = re.sub(pattern,':"True"',text)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
{"name":"John", "isAdult:"True", "Address":"42 True Street SomeLand"}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the quotes? `"True"` is very different than `true`. You should consider replacing `True` with `true` instead of `"True"` as `true` is a valid boolean value in JSON, whereas `"True"` will be a string.

Comment: Correction:  meant to use negative lookbehind: `(?<!\\)":True`